# Font no render | antialiasing in Phpstorm 10 | Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, phpstorm

**Capture:**

[Problem font, antialising](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BUVb.png)

My configuration:

**java -version:**

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

**phpstorm64.vmoptions:**

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=540m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

**echo $JAVA_HOME:**

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin
```

Comment: There's a guide at SuperUser for IntelliJ Idea that fixes the font problem. Try searching there.

Comment: why in hell in this downvoted, when its a legit issue, our company had to downgrade to 8 because of this

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a new feature in PhpStorm 10. Open up PhpStorm's preferences and go to [Appearance & Behavior > Appearance]. Under the "Antialiasing" section, change "Editor" to "Greyscale" or "no antialiasing". There are a few other options. Play with it and see what you like.